# Python MySQL - All queries yield a "None" result

Tags: python, mysql

ANY query passed through yields "None" result:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'host':             'localhost',
    'user':             'root',
    'password':         '',
    'raise_on_warnings':True    
}
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
csr = conn.cursor()
result = csr.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
print(result)
```

Result:

> None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `fetchall()` method as written [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).
(Also you are not giving any database).

`csr.execute(some_query)` does not return any value. This method just change is own value, and you can collect it calling `csr.fetchall()`, that returns a list of tuples that you can iterate with a for loop or using whatever way you want.

```py
import mysql.connector
config = {
    'host':              'localhost',
    'user':              'root',
    'password':          '',
    'database':          'database_name',
    'raise_on_warnings': True    
}
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
csr = conn.cursor()
csr.execute('SELECT * FROM some_table_of_given_database')
result = csr.fetchall()
print(result)
conn.close()
```

Comment: *face palm! Thanks, I looked everywhere any couldn't find an answer!

Comment: If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped and the question could be closed.